# Identify if monthly or annual payment

Tags: jquery, json, object

I'm trying to difference whether a customer decides to pay a monthly or annual subscription. The thing is that in the button that makes the action of subscription, I have different properties and one of them is the payment option that has an object inside of it:

```
<button 
 class="button azul enviar ga-event subscription-charge hide-oxxo" 
 id="button-plan-frecuente" 
 data-toggle="modal" 
 data-target="{!! $subWrappperClass !!}" 
 data-event-category="Contratos" 
 data-payment-options=
'{
  "periodicity":
    {
     "month":
      {
       "_id":"5ba43f8c8269750b1e7f5fb5",
       "conekta":"saas_frecuente_mensual",
       "paypal":"2ZLSZBT4AT896"
      },
     "annual":
      {
       "_id":"5c66fff8b071e20f9804de18",
       "conekta":"saas_frecuente_anual",
       "paypal":"76J5PW7YQA2H4"
      }
     }
 }' 
 data-product=
'{
 "user_id":"{!! $document->user->id !!}",
 "product_id":"{!! $document->id !!}",
 "product_type":"unregistered_document"
}' 
 value="plan">
  SUSCRÍBETE
</button>
```

I've already done the function to access to a monthly subscription, but I don't know how to make it dynamic so I can access both of them (monthly or annual) depending on what the customer decides.

```
if (subscriptionChargeBtn.length > 0) {
        subscriptionChargeBtn.on ('click touch', function (event){
         var btn = $(this);
         var paymentOptions =  JSON.parse (btn.attr ('data-payment-options'));
         var productOptions =  btn.attr('data-product');
         $("#custom_parms").val (productOptions);
         $("#hosted_button_id").val (paymentOptions.periodicity.month.paypal);
         $('#conekta_plan_id').val (paymentOptions.periodicity.month.conekta);
         $("#membership_id").val (paymentOptions.periodicity.month._id);
        });
      }
```

Comment: How do you know which plan the user has selected? Whatever the criterion, it seems that you could handle it with a simple `if-else` block.

Comment: Or `paymentOptions.periodicity[variableContainingMonthOrAnnual].paypal`